# Install IE 8 on a Virtual Box VM?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to install ie version 8  in a virtual box. I downloaded several files from microsoft website. One of them after start extracting the show me an language related error all the others said that the .exe file is not a valid Win32 application.

Can anyone help me how to install this??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What operating system are you running on your VirtualBox? Because you are getting a Win32 error, I would suggest you are running a 32-bit Windows OS and have downloaded a 64-bit installer.

When downloading from Microsoft, double-check you are downloading a 32-bit installer (32-bit and x86 are essentially the same thing).

IE 8 for XP: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=43